# Re-initialize object during setup to override global init when using UniversalTelegramBot

Tags: c++, arduino, telegram-bot

I am working to implement the UniversalTelegramBot (https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot) and in all examples, I can see that the bot is being declared as a global variable. This requires the variable BOTtoken to be available very early in the boot sequence, and it is there defined as a fixed value.

I am trying to store the BOTtoken in EEPROM and would like to have the bot defined during setup, while keeping its global scope.

Is it possible? (let me know if you need the code)

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(SECRET_BOT_TOKEN, client); // here it is defined at the global level

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);

    ReadUsersFromEEPROM(); // then I read some users from the EEPROM, including the token

    UniversalTelegramBot bot(bot_token, client); // here is where I would like the init of the BOT to be, so it use the bot_token I just read from EEPROM, but if I re-declare like this it does not overrride the global setup and if I remove the global declaration, this remains local.


}
```

Comment: Can't you return the `UniversalTelegramBot` instance from `setup()` and write `UniversalTelegramBot bot = setup()` there?

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I found the answer. Actually, the original coder of the Universal Telegram Bot code replied to me in GitHub.

The part I was missing was to define bot as a pointer in the global scope and insiide the setup use the NEW tag...

bot = new UniversalTelegramBot (bot_token, client);

There is an example here:
https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot/blob/master/examples/ESP8266/UsingWiFiManager/UsingWiFiManager.ino

Thank you all!!!